# How to access the main page control values in user control

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, user-controls

I have so many controls in dot net aspx page , i want to access the some control values in users control page. Without using any property (variable ) any options available..?

Default.aspx:

---

```
 <input type="hidden" name="Hidden1" value="1" />
 <input type="hidden" name="Hidden2" value="2" />
 <input type="hidden" name="Hidden3" value="3" />
```

UserControl1.ascx:

---

```
Response.write("Hidden 1 Value" & Request("Hidden1"))
Response.write("Hidden 2 Value" & Request("Hidden2"))
Response.write("Hidden 3 Value" & Request("Hidden3"))
```

Comment: could you clarify what your goal is with a small code example?

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve, for example, a textbox defined in the aspx page from an ascx control contained in it you could try:

```
Dim myTextBox As TextBox = Ctype(Me.Parent.FindControl("myTextBoxName"), TextBox)
```

Note that the control you want to retrieve must have a `runat="server"` attribute otherwise it can  not be seen server side.

In your question you posted three controls without `runat="server"`; you could use instead:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" Value="1" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField2" runat="server" Value="2" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField3" runat="server" Value="3" />
```

In this case the above command would become:

```
Dim myHiddenField As HiddenField = Ctype(Me.Parent.FindControl("myHiddenFieldName"), HiddenField)
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly in order to find a control in code behind it must be a server side control and you can get the value of aspx page control from user control as follows

Use this code in your User Controls code behind

```
           var tb = (TextBox)this.Parent.FindControl("myTextBox");
           string s = tb.Text;//you'll get the value of TextBox in s
```

Here "myTextBox" is the id of TextBox in my aspx page.

**Note**: I took myTextBox and User Control in the same container of my aspx page.